# Get minimum from result with GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have table it store hierarchy data in MySQL this table store stable relation but if each user less than 1000 buy removed and user User a lower level replace this is my code and work fine, after `GROUP BY` it contain all ancestor of descendant with compare then `COUNT(*) AS level` count level each user. This I have SQL code to compress data According to minimum buy for each user

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| ancestor_id | descendant_id | path_length |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|           1 |             1 |           0 |
|           1 |             2 |           1 |
|           1 |             3 |           1 |
|           1 |             4 |           2 |
|           1 |             5 |           3 |
|           1 |             6 |           4 |
|           2 |             2 |           0 |
|           2 |             4 |           1 |
|           2 |             5 |           2 |
|           2 |             6 |           3 |
|           3 |             3 |           0 |
|           4 |             4 |           0 |
|           4 |             5 |           1 |
|           4 |             6 |           2 |
|           5 |             5 |           0 |
|           5 |             6 |           1 |
|           6 |             6 |           0 |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

This is table buy

```
+--------+--------+
| userid | amount |
+--------+--------+
|      2 |   2000 |
|      4 |   6000 |
|      6 |   7000 |
|      1 |   7000 |
```

SQL code

```
 SELECT a.* 


FROM
    ( SELECT userid 
       FROM webineh_user_buys 
      GROUP BY userid
      HAVING SUM(amount) >= 1000
    ) AS buys_d 

JOIN
    webineh_prefix_nodes_paths AS a 
    ON a.descendant_id = buys_d.userid

 JOIN  
    (
        SELECT userid  
        FROM webineh_user_buys 
        GROUP BY userid
        HAVING SUM(amount) >= 1000
    ) AS buys_a on (a.ancestor_id = buys_a.userid )


  JOIN 
     ( SELECT descendant_id
            , MAX(path_length) path_length 
         FROM webineh_prefix_nodes_paths 
         where a.ancestor_id = ancestor_id
        GROUP
           BY descendant_id
     ) b
    ON b.descendant_id = a.descendant_id
   AND b.path_length = a.path_length



 GROUP BY a.descendant_id, a.ancestor_id
```

I need get max path_length where ancestor_id have At least 1000 amount buy but have error in where in subquery where a.ancestor_id = ancestor_id error code

> 1054 - Unknown column 'a.ancestor_id' in 'where clause'

I add [SQLFidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4e50/13) demo.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: ...but I wonder if this is what you're after... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4e50/9

Comment: it must get only userid have buy more than 1000 in you sqlfilde not use this option

Comment: Well, no one who bought anything ever bought less than 1000, so it didn't seem relevant - but easy enough to fix, right? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4e50/12

Comment: my scenario very easy each parent have less than 1000 bought and each self descendant , but with hierarchy relation

Comment: Unfortunately, that statement (like so many here) makes no sense.

Comment: this [sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4e50/6) work fine but it contain multiply descendant_id i need to get row with minimum path_length Except zero , like for descendant_id 6 must get path_length 2

Comment: You should end your phrases in your question. Like this.

Comment: One implication is that `webineh_user_buys` has no PRIMARY KEY, which may well prove problematic.

Comment: i update my question and just have one error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [group by and get minimum row in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903926/group-by-and-get-minimum-row-in-mysql)

Comment: Looks like a deliberate copy-and-paste of your earlier question. Please don't do that, and furthermore, please _do_ use the shift key occasionally. All lower-case is harder to read, and creates editing work for someone else.

Comment: yes , i remove duplicate after get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
select     m.userid  as descendant,
           p.ancestor_id,
           p.path_length
from       (
            select     b1.userid, 
                       min(case when b2.amount >= 1000 
                                then p.path_length 
                           end) as path_length 
            from       (select   userid, sum(amount) amount
                        from     webineh_user_buys 
                        group by userid
                        having   sum(amount) >= 1000
                       ) as b1
            left join  webineh_prefix_nodes_paths p
                    on p.descendant_id = b1.userid
                   and p.path_length > 0
            left join  (select   userid, sum(amount) amount
                        from     webineh_user_buys 
                        group by userid) as b2
                    on p.ancestor_id = b2.userid
            group by   b1.userid
           ) as m
left join  webineh_prefix_nodes_paths p
        on p.descendant_id = m.userid
       and p.path_length = m.path_length
order by   m.userid
```

Output for sample data in the question:

```
| userid | ancestor_id | path_length |
|--------|-------------|-------------|
|      1 |      (null) |      (null) |
|      2 |           1 |           1 |
|      4 |           2 |           1 |
|      6 |           4 |           2 |
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0704e0/4)

Comment: thanks , but have bug, when sum buy user 4 contain , 100 , 800 = 900 then must dont show ... but show http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0704e0/1